# Unit test generator for ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: testing, asp.net-web-api

Can you recommend a unit test generator for ASP.NET WebAPI? I would prefer one that goes "over the wire" so that routes are covered, but even one that generates stubs directly against the controller classes would be a huge benefit.

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but the [Unit Test Generator](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/45208924-e7b0-45df-8cff-165b505a38d7) can do some work for you. Another option would be the "[smart unit tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn823749%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)" introduced with [VS2015](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2014/11/12/opening-up-visual-studio-and-net-to-every-developer-any-application-net-server-core-open-source-and-cross-platform-visual-studio-community-2013-and-preview-of-visual-studio-2015-and-net-2015.aspx).

Comment: I wish that tool had customizable Razor templates.